# Win32 COMBOBOX dont draw dropdown-list

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, dropdown, drawing

i create in win32 c++ plugin on a *.rc-file a COMBOBOX with drop-down-list:

```
COMBOBOX   IDC_CCODE_EDT_PNR,60,18,83,27,CBS_DROPDOWN | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_SORT | CBS_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
```

Create the owner window by:

```
_hSelf = ::CreateDialogParam(_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(dialogID), _hParent, dlgProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
```

On init requester is setting the items by:

```
::SendMessage(cbPointCode, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)StringTools::GetWString(codes->at(i)).c_str());
```

On open drop-down-list is resizing okay, but items is not drawing, black text on black background. Only after mouse over is draw the item.

[image: dropdownbox effect]

What must i do to init drawing drop-down-list on open?

regards Mario

(edit add create window)

Comment: Do you have any kind of OnColor in the owning dialog?

Comment: No, must catch the OnColor Event by the owner window?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] please?

Comment: Hello IInspectable,
the window is running as DockingDlgInterface on notepad++-plugin.
An "minimal reproducible example" require an full c++ notepad++ plugin-project.

Comment: Yes, certain window messages are sent to the parent rather than the control itself.  I've never quite understood the logic of it.

Comment: @MarkRansom how else are pre-made controls supposed to customize themselves to their parent UIs if the parents aren't involved in the processing?

Answer (score 0):

the problem has not the c++ and win32 compenents.
I have use the notepad++ version 8.4.6, that was the cause.
After update to 8.6 works all fine...

Best regards to your all

Comment: Could you please mark answer for completion of the question?